# Why do errors from Functions Logger not show up in Error Reporting?

Tags: firebase, logging, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-stackdriver

In my Firebase Functions, I was mainly using `console.error(new Error("some error"))`. These things show up in the logs interface and the (Stackdriver) Error Reporting overview.

Then I found out about Firebase Functions Logger [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/logger_). It appeals to me because the API makes it very easy to log some object with data together with the message, and it is nicely tucked away in the logs interface. Overall it just seems like that's what you are supposed to use instead of the plain old `console`, because it is an official Firebase API, and so I started using it in various places.

Now I find out that my errors logged with `logger.error()` do not show up in GCloud Error Reporting ‍♂️ I have been missing loads of errors, thinking everything was running smoothly.

It is a mystery to me why these errors do not show in the error reporting. I think there should be a big fat warning in the logger docs if this is expected behavior.

There are other APIs for error reporting too, but they seem quite verbose and specifically targeting Stackdriver. I just want something simple to use like `console.error` and also see these errors in the log interface.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the logger API?

I recently switched to Node12 for my functions. Possibly the Stackdriver disconnect started then, but I can't imagine this being a bug, since the Node12 runtime has been out of preview for a long time.

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: `import { logger } from "firebase-functions";`  and then `logger.error("Some error", { some, data })`

Answer (score 0):

There was [a significant change](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/migrating/nodejs-runtimes#nodejs-10-changes) to how logging works between nodejs8 and nodejs10. I see that you recently upgraded to nodejs14, were you coming from nodejs8 by any chance?

Comment: I switched to nodejs12 from nodejs10. 14 is still in preview for cloud functions AFAIK and that is not something I'd risk because I've been bitten by preview versions before when indeed I switched from 8 to 10.